# How do you functional test your Commerce Kickstart 2.0 projects?

Tags: commerce

Since Commerce Kickstart 2.0 has its own Drupal installation, I don't see how to use SimpleTest with it.  I did find this [documentation](https://drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/utilizing-core-apis/writing-simpletests-commerce-modules) for the regular Drupal Commerce, not Commerce Kickstart 2 from what I can gather.  When I try to find what it alludes to in this documentation (CommerceBaseTestCase ), this does not exist in the Commerce Kickstart install that I can find.

So, how are people testing with Commerce Kickstart 2?  Let me be clearer with my question.  I have already installed Commerce Kickstart 2 and done some development.  I now want to create products and other elements programatically using SimpleTest to do functional testing.  However, SimpleTest starts with a clean install of Drupal.  This is not possible to use with Commerce Kickstart 2.0 because it has its OWN drupal version, and its not just a set of modules that I could enable programatically.

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I already have Commerce Kickstart installed and have done development.  I now want to do functional testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Commerce Kickstart 2 on your local environment and it would automatic have some data. If you do not know have a development environment I would recommend you to use [Lazy Dubuntu](http://lazydubuntu.com) (if you wish to build it on Ubuntu computer) or [Acquia Dev Desktop 2](https://www.acquia.com/downloads) for Mac or Windows.

If you do not want to used your local environment you can use [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/) to test it out for free.

[image: Commece]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to playaround:

- Free https://pantheon.io/
- Free https://insight.acquia.com/free/register
- Free http://simplytest.me/

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I already have Commerce Kickstart installed and have done development.  I now want to do functional testing.